# ヘルプ センターの「自分の質問にプラス票がつく」の説明が +5 のまま

Tags: バグ, 完了, ヘルプ

[ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)

> 信用度は投票により次のように変化します：
>
> +5　自分の質問にプラス票がつく

自分の質問にプラス票がついた場合は +10 に仕様変更されたはずです。
旧仕様のままの表記となっています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nice catch な指摘です。モデレーター権限で修正しておきました。ありがとうございます！

> 信用度は投票により次のように変化します：
>
> +10　自分の質問にプラス票がつく